# Laravel Shibboleth package

Tags: laravel, shibboleth

How to set up and use laravel **shibboleth package**,

supposing that in my organization there are distinct user roles? My version of **Laravel Framework is 5.7.26**. I initially tried to install it (with `composer require razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth` via cmd) with no success.

Below is the result of my attempt to install it. Any idea?

```
" Problem 1
- Installation request for razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth ^3.0 
  -> satisfiable by razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth[3.0.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.26
- razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth 3.0.0 requires laravel/framework 5.4.* || 5.5.* 
  -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v5.7.26].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v5.7.26].
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.26, required as 5.7.*) 
  -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.26].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content."
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your project it might be easiest to downgrade your Laravel framework version to 5.5. You'll see on the razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth) page that it requires Laravel 5.4 or 5.5. On the package's github profile you'll see that there's an issue logged for [Laravel 5.6](https://github.com/razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth/issues/11) support and that the latest [commit](https://github.com/razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth/commits/master) was on 25 Jan 2018, so it is not very up to date. I recommend always checking these things before deciding on using a package.

To downgrade to Laravel 5.5, you'll need to change your `composer.json` file to to require `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*"`. You'll also need to check that all your other dependencies are compatible with 5.5. If they are not, you'll also need to downgrade them to compatible versions.

Lastly, consider using [uabookstores/laravel-shibboleth](https://packagist.org/packages/uabookstores/laravel-shibboleth) or [prasad/laravel-shibboleth](https://packagist.org/packages/prasad/laravel-shibboleth) which are forks of razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth that have Laravel 5.7 support.

Comment: I agree - way simpler to use 5.5 - which is a solid version.

Comment: By the way, those other 2 AUTHOR/laravel-shibboleth alternative versions ... those would have been created by the forking steps I loosely described in my answer.

Comment: At minimum, yes, but they also would've had to be updated if it touched any breaking changes between updates and tested properly.

Comment: Guys, I must not downgrade laravel. I try with this and we'll see : https://packagist.org/packages/uabookstores/laravel-shibboleth

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade laravel.  Or you can fork shibboleth, change the composer.json requirements/limits, then start testing to see if the package works with 5.7

1. fork this into your github account https://github.com/razorbacks/laravel-shibboleth
2. clone your new forked copy to local work machine
3. edit composer.json to adjust limits/requirements
4. commit and push back to your forked copy

Now, in your project that uses the package you'll need to point to your copy/fork instead of the original public version of the package.

1. add your fork to the "repositories" section of composer.json (NOT the same composer.json ... this is the laravel project composer.json)
2. run composer update

Your new repositories section in the composer.json file should look something like this...

`"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME/laravel-shibboleth"
    }]`

Comment: How can I do that? Could you assist?

Comment: Ya, I'll try.  I think stackoverflow has a way to start a direct chat.  ... Not totally sure  how to do it.

Comment: @Konstantinos - I've added some info.  Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not easy to chat from here! If convenient, please contact me at konrms@gmail.com. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Konstantinos I sent you an email.  I think we can share a fork of this package in github and get it working the way you want - without having to share your actual project code.